# background overflow in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason when I'm shrinking the size of the windows, there is a gap on the right edge of the website, showing the background.
It gets worse when I'm shrinking it more. Any ideas on how to fix that? I have some absolute elements, maybe that's why?

[image]

Another thing is that it gave me an idea to deliberately make those gaps but on both sides, showing the page background, how to do it?

Thanks alot for reading and helping.

Comment: You need to upload your CSS and HTML or we can't really help I'm afraid. An image doesn't give enough information.

Comment: Hey Oliver, thank you for answering.
I managed to fix that by adding to .container>>overflow:hidden

The second question is still valid though.

Comment: Have a play with adding a `max-width` to the element you want to be in the center, then also apply `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`. Have a google / play and see what you can put together then ask a question with your HTML and CSS in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body{
   background-image: url("img_name.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

or try to set margin to auto or set the max-width.